# Impressão em 2 vias Jaspersoft Studio

Tags: jasper, jaspersoft-studio

- Tenho um report Master que possui duas "Detail Band", com uma altura definida, que não deve ser modificada.
- Meu SubRelatorio também possui uma "Detail Band", com um JRBeanCollectionDataSource, os parâmetros estão sendo passados sem maiores problemas, PORÉM, não está sendo feita a paginação da forma como eu gostaria.
- Preciso que fique DUAS vias na mesma página, como um canhoto, quando são poucos itens funciona, mas existem casos em que podem ter até 200 itens, e eles precisam estar paginados, mantendo a altura fixa.

[image: Uma imagem ilustrativa para melhor explanar o resultado que preciso.]

- No momento, quando existem muitos itens, ele simplesmente mostra de forma contínua. Já tentei várias combinações com Stretch e No Stretch, Split Type da Band, realmente não consegui chegar a uma solução.
- Eu consegui fazer um Exemplo Mínimo Verificável como o próprio StackOverFlow recomenda... segue o link do repositório - https://github.com/Sibelly/jasper-subrelatorios

Comment: E se você determinasse um detail band apenas que tive o tamanho de meia folha A4, já que os dois são iguais automaticamente ele colocaria dois em uma folha

Comment: Então, eu lembro que tinha tentado na época, porém a detail band não ficava com a altura truncada sabe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu consegui resolver esse problema truncando a quantidade de itens por página no próprio código. Criei um método com a lógica responsável por quebrar os itens. Basicamente é o trecho de código a seguir:

```
       while (quantidadeDeItens > 0) {
            if (quantidadeDeItens <= quantidadeDeItensPorPagina) {
                itensPaginados.addAll(produtos.subList(i, produtos.size()));

                // Workaround para deixar o layout sempre do mesmo tamanho
                if (itensPaginados.size() < quantidadeDeItensPorPagina) {
                    while (itensPaginados.size() < quantidadeDeItensPorPagina) {
                        Produto item = new Produto();
                        itensPaginados.add(item);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                itensPaginados.addAll(produtos.subList(i, j));
            }

            paginaCorrente = paginaCorrente + 1;

            JasperPrint printReport = setarParametrosParaImpressao(itensPaginados, cliente, totalPaginas, paginaCorrente);
            listaDeProdutosParaImpressao.add(printReport);

            i = i + quantidadeDeItensPorPagina;
            j = j + quantidadeDeItensPorPagina;
            quantidadeDeItens = quantidadeDeItens - quantidadeDeItensPorPagina;
            itensPaginados = new ArrayList<>();

        }
```

Porém eu tive que modificar a maneira como é gerado o JasperPrint. Não colocarei aqui pois ficaria muito extenso, para quem tiver interesse só verificar nesse [repositório](https://github.com/sibelly/jasper-subrelatorios).

Esqueci de responder antes, mas espero que ajude alguém um dia. ;)